# Pandas: how to concatenate a MultiIndex DataFrame with a single index DataFrame, and custom ordering

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, concatenation

I have a MultiIndex pandas DataFrame `df_multi` like:

```
import pandas as pd

df_multi = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'A1', 0,234,2002],['A', 'A1', 1,324,2550],
['A', 'A1', 2,345,3207],['A', 'A1', 3,458,4560],['A', 'A2', 0,569,1980],
['A', 'A2', 1,657,2314],['A', 'A2', 2,768,4568],['A', 'A2', 3,823,5761]], 
columns=['Product','Scenario','Time','Quantity','Price']).set_index(
['Product', 'Scenario'])
```

and a single index DataFrame `df_single` like:

```
df_single = pd.DataFrame([['A', -3,100],['A', -2,100], ['A', -1,100]],
columns=['Product','Time','Quantity']).set_index(['Product'])
```

For every 'Product' in the first index level of `df_multi`, and for every 'Scenario' in its second level, I would like to append/concatenate the rows in `df_single`, which contain some negative 'Time' values to be appended before the positive 'Time' values in `df_multi` begin.

I would furthermore like the resulting DataFrame to be first MultiIndexed by ['Product','Scenario'] (just like `df_multi`), then secondly with the rows ordered by ascending value of 'Time'. In other words, the desired result is:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'A1', -3,100,'NaN'],['A', 'A1', -2,100,'NaN'],
['A', 'A1', -1,100,'NaN'],['A', 'A1', 0,234,2002],['A', 'A1', 1,324,2550],
['A', 'A1', 2,345,3207],['A', 'A1', 3,458,4560],['A','A2', -3,100,'NaN'],
['A', 'A2', -2,100,'NaN'],['A', 'A2', -1,100,'NaN'],['A', 'A2', 0,569,1980],
['A', 'A2', 1,657,2314],['A', 'A2', 2,768,4568],['A', 'A2', 3,823,5761]],
columns=['Product','Scenario','Time','Quantity','Price']).set_index(
['Product', 'Scenario'])
```

**EDIT:**

- `df_single` has no 'Scenario' values, which can be confusing. As long as 'Product' matches, the same rows of `df_single` are to be appended to every scenario in `df_multi`, and they simply "inherit" the Scenario values for free.
- The actual DataFrames I'm working with are rather large (few thousand 'Product', few thousand 'Scenario' per product, and a few hundred 'Time' steps per scenario, plus extra columns which I did not write in the example), so I need to do this in a fully automated (and hopefully fast) way.

I tried to implement this with all of `join`, `concat` and `merge`, and I did not succeed. What would be the best way of achieving the desired result?

Comment: There is no *Scenario* in *df_single*. Do we split *df_single's* product rows equally for each distinct scenario in *df_multi*? Are we assured rows will evenly split always like this posted example of 3 and 3?

Comment: Indeed there's no scenario in df_single, because the new rows represented in df_single are the same for every scenario. As long as the 'Product' matches en df_multi and df_single, I want to append the same slice of df_single to every scenario in df_multi, and automatically assign it the "current" scenario value.

Comment: Are you aware there are duplicates in *df_single*? If they are legitimate records, why then not append all 6 to both *A1* and *A2* scenarios instead of 3 and 3?

Comment: Apologies about the duplicates, I had a bit of a copy-paste issue there. I have now removed them. Is there a way to visualize the DataFrame the code is producing directly in Stackoverflow?

Comment: (If you want people to test this on larger dataframes for scaleability, please edit the dataframe snippets to be seeded-random data of length 10**N rows. The extra columns shouldn't matter much, ignore them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider resetting indexes as columns for a `merge`, followed by a `groupby` aggregation only to return one occurrence per group and avoid duplicates. Afterwards, run a concatenation, `concat`, followed by column sorting and setting back the multi-index.

```
# MERGE AND AGGREGATION
df_temp = df_multi.reset_index().merge(df_single.reset_index(), on='Product', suffixes=['','_'])\
                                .groupby(['Product', 'Scenario', 'Time_'])['Quantity_'].max()\
                                .reset_index().rename(columns={'Time_':'Time','Quantity_':'Quantity'})

# ROW BIND CONCATENATION
df_final = pd.concat([df_multi.reset_index(), df_temp])\
                    .sort_values(['Product','Scenario', 'Time'])\
                    .set_index(['Product', 'Scenario'])[['Time', 'Quantity', 'Price']]
print(df_final)
#                   Time  Quantity   Price
# Product Scenario                        
# A       A1          -3       100     NaN
#         A1          -2       100     NaN
#         A1          -1       100     NaN
#         A1           0       234  2002.0
#         A1           1       324  2550.0
#         A1           2       345  3207.0
#         A1           3       458  4560.0
#         A2          -3       100     NaN
#         A2          -2       100     NaN
#         A2          -1       100     NaN
#         A2           0       569  1980.0
#         A2           1       657  2314.0
#         A2           2       768  4568.0
#         A2           3       823  5761.0
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I'm curious about speed/scalability. I will test it on the real data I'm using to see how it performs on large dataframes.